# Перевод каждой цифры в двоичную систему счисления: двоично-десятичный код — BCD

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def convert():
     Integer_input= int(numb, 10)
     Binary_output= bin(integer_input)[2:].zfill(4)
     converted =str(Binary_output)
     return converted
```

Это код работает если ввожу 16 то получу 10000, а мне надо чтобы получилось 00010110

Используется Python 3.5

Comment: Не понял логики, по которой из 16 должно получиться 00010110

Comment: 1= 0001 6 =0110

Comment: Теперь понял. .

Comment: Возможно ли как-то взять по одному цифру из исходного данного и сделать как я хочу

Comment: Приводи число к строковому виду, затем беги посимвольно приводя к инту и выполняй те же операции

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто считайте, что исходная строка записана в шестнадцатеричном виде:

```
numb = '16'

integer_input= int(numb, 16)  # Переводим из 16-ричной в десятичную, получаем 22
binary_output= bin(integer_input)[2:].zfill(len(numb.strip())*4)  # на каждую исходную цифру по 4 двоичных

print(binary_output)  # 00010110
```

По сути это [двоично-десятичное кодирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4).

Comment: Мне надо с 10го

Comment: Что значит "с 10го"?

Comment: Из 10 ной в 2 ную

Comment: @user270218, это не важно. Подставляйте 16 - получите 00010110, подставляете например 48 - получаете 01001000. Результат, как я понимаю, соответствует требуемому.

Comment: Всё отлично спасибо большое я не заметил что так можно

Comment: @user270218 `0b00010110` (основание 2) равно `22` (основание 10). `0x16` (основание 16) равно `22` (основание 10), то есть `16 != 0x16 == 0b00010110 == 22`